# Add shadow around a masked UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mask

I am trying to create a pop-over which will have a tip. Following is the code for this

```
tipView.frame = CGRect(x: at.x - size.width, y: at.y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        let imgView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tipView.frame.width, height: tipView.frame.height))
        imgView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "popup.png")
        tipView.mask = imgView
```

I masked UIView with an image which is in the shape of pop-over.

Now I want to add shadow to the UIView on all 4 sides. I tried all the methods. But the shadow is not visible

[image]

Comment: Could you please add image what you want?

Comment: You could use `UIPopoverPresentationController` instead of creating your own custom view. And where is the code in which you tried to add the shadow.

Comment: @SagarChauhan update question

Comment: @SushilSharma, Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code to add shadow and corner radius to tipView. Clear `backgroundColor` and make `clipsToBounds = false` of tipView.

```
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: tipView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    shapeLayer.masksToBounds = false

    shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    shapeLayer.shadowPath = shapeLayer.path
    shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 2.0

    tipView.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your view layer:

```
// set the corner radius
layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
layer.masksToBounds = false
// set the shadow properties
layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
```

Please go through the this [link](https://medium.com/bytes-of-bits/swift-tips-adding-rounded-corners-and-shadows-to-a-uiview-691f67b83e4a) for details